# Stopping an event listener after a condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I have a code similar to this:

```
emitter.on('request', request => {
    if(condition) doSomething(request);
});

function doSomething(request){
    emitter.on('message', message => {
        if(anotherCondition){
            //
            //Some code to send something
            //
        }
    })
}
```

Basically, if that's not clear, I'm trying to have a listener wait for a request then send back *whatever* and wait for the receiver's response to that *whatever* I sent. However, when this happens, the `on('message'` listener is still active and the next request the emitter gets it sends the the *whatever* **twice**. The next time, it sends the *whatever* **three** times. How do I safely stop this?

Comment: Use `emitter.once('message', …)`?

Comment: As Bergi said, `emitter.once` is the way to go. Another, more cumbersome way could be to manually call `off` within the `emitter.on('message')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can observe from your code that you are creating a new listener everytime you call doSomething(). Therefore the number of times you receive the message increases everytime you call doSomething()

You should define the emitter.on('message'.... block outside the doSomething() and
instead just emit the event emit('message'... inside the doSomething() to emit the event or use removeListener('message.... for disabling the event emitter under certain circumstances.

If you maintain 1 emitter and 1 listener at all times,you should be fine.

This should mostly be what you are expecting.